# Find End of line (/n) in EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-textattributes

I have a edittext, i want to append some characters before text on each line of the edit text depending upon the button pressed.
for example

```
if( fivespacesbutton is pressed )
then
append five spaces on each line the function OnClick(View v) has called.
```

I think if i get to know about end of line (/n) then i will append five spaces before each line.

any idea how can i get /n from

```
EditText scene=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String text = scene.getText().toString();
String result = "";
for (String line : text.split("\n"))
{
   result += "    " + line + "\n";
}
scene.setText(result);
```